# How to check if Python request exists or not in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I need to check if `python` `flask` app that gets a `POST` `json` request.

But before returning anything, I need to check if that `json` exists or not.

Below is my code.

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def get_predicted_values():
    response_ = {}
    predicted_values_list = []
    request_data = request.get_json()

    path = request_data["fpath"]

    if path:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

But this way it gives an error (when I intentionally not passing any `json` object, because I need to check my `if` condition works above)

error is:

> path = request_data["fpath"]
> KeyError: 'fpath'

I want to tackle this error (if that `json` block is absent, don't throw an error, just do anything else (i.e prints `Not Found` instead of the above error)), I even used a `try` - `except` and still the error is the same.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try `is_json`

```
 if not request.is_json:
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.is_json